# How to show content for posts of a specific category only

Tags: content, excerpt

I show excerpts of all posts at this site. Which works fine.

However, I would like show content for posts of a specific category, while keeping all others showing excerpts.

Is it possible, without a plugin? With a filter in functions.php, etc.?

Working with 3.1.4, twentyten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in_category` function to test if the current post in the loop is in the specific category you want to display full content for.

For example

```
if ( in_category( 'my_category') ) :
    the_content();
else :
    the_excerpt();
endif;
```

For more information on the `in_category` function see the WordPress codex at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category